# How to count the number of times a function was called, the FP way

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am currently working through [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) with Haskell. Exercise 1.15 asks how many times a function is called. The idea is probably that you should use the substitution method, but I would like to know how to do so in code.

In an imperative language one can keep a global variable and increment it every time the function is called. But how would you go about it in Haskell (or the pure functional way)?

Comment: If only for debugging, you can use `Debug.Trace`'s `trace` function. It breaks referential transparency, but if you're debugging or exploring that should be fine.

Comment: Ahem, I think SICP is actually expecting the count to be either 0 or 1 - the jist being "is the function evaluated or not?". There isn't a purely functional way of counting how many times a function is called. The answers below provide good monadic "solutions" but they depend in the function to be counted being "run" within the respective monad. This is an important nit-pick - they don't count general functions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `Writer` monad to accomplish this, provided that all of the calls to the function in question can be grouped together into a `do` block:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer

myFunc :: Int -> Int -> Writer (Sum Int) Int
myFunc a b = tell (Sum 1) >> return (a + b)

callMyFunc :: ((Int, Int, Int), Sum Int)
callMyFunc = runWriter $ do a <- myFunc 2 3
                            b <- myFunc 8 7
                            c <- myFunc 3 5
                            return (a, b, c)

main = putStrLn $
    "myFunc was called "
        ++ show (getSum $ snd callMyFunc)
        ++ " times and produced "
        ++ show (fst callMyFunc)
```

Which outputs:

```
myFunc was called 3 times and produced (5,15,8)
```

Answer (score 7):

It sounds to me like you need to have some kind of counter regardless of whether you go with a functional or a non-functional way. In Haskell, you could use the `State` Monad to keep track of the state:

```
import Control.Monad.State

someFunc x = do
    num <- get
    put (num + 1)
    return $ x * x

runSomeFuncs = do
    someFunc 1
    someFunc 2
    someFunc 3

main = do
    let (res, state) = runState runSomeFuncs 0
    putStrLn ("result: " ++ (show res))
    putStrLn ("# of calls: " ++ show state)
```

Here, you want to keep track of how many times `someFunc` got called, so we pass an integer in as the state and increment the integer every time the function gets called by using:

```
num <- get
put (num + 1)
```

and then increment it by 1 and `put` it back. If you run this script, it should print

```
result: 9
# of calls: 3
```

Comment: Or `modify (+ 1)` instead of `get`ting and `put`ting.

Comment: Using `State` here allows to also depend on the counter, and creates an unnecessary data dependency (that would limit parallelism, for example).  You can use `Writer` instead, with `Sum Int` as the `Monoid`, and then `tell (Sum 1)` to increase the counter. This nicely exploits the associativity of addition, and allows even CSE when calling the same Writer computation multiple times.

Comment: @Peaker Expand that and post it as an answer.