# I want to count the number of times a function gets called without putting a counter inside that function

Tags: c#

Because of limitations from my higher-ups I cannot edit the software itself, however I want to be able to do something every time a function in another cs goes off.

I looked at [How to count the number of times a function was called, the FP way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920129/how-to-count-the-number-of-times-a-function-was-called-the-fp-way)
however I couldn't find a "snd callMyFunc" paralell for c#.

Comment: Debuggers and profilers can show this info pretty easily, assuming you're able to attach a debugger to the running program.

Comment: I am using a debugger, I just want my own function that would interact with that function.

Comment: is it possible to add a method that just increments, before and/or after that line of code you, can't edit?.then again I don't know how complex your software is